# Differences between 2nd order low pass filters

Tags: low-pass, sallen-key

I don’t know how to design filters, but I need a second order low pass filter. I searched them on the internet and found two schemes. One is Sallen-Key, and the other I don’t know what is called. Question: what is the difference and which is better to use? How is the filter calculated in Figure 42?

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Comment: You made me laugh by using "Salena Kay" filters and then selecting the correct "Sallen-Key" tag. :D

Comment: The name of the second filter is literally typed out beneath the picture -> Butterworth

Comment: Which one to use, depends on your use-case which you didn't note.

Comment: So, we do expect you to do a bit of research: Both filter types have wikipedia pages, and we can't tell you what is "better" if you don't tell us anything about what your metric for "good" is. Filters have different properties, like stopband suppression, passband flatness, phase linearity, steepness of transition, and you design them to fit your application. Without any info on the application, there's no "better" filter.

Comment: There are filter shapes, and filter implementations, don't confuse the two. Butterworth, Chebyshev, Bessel are shapes. Sallen-Key is an implementation (2nd order non-inverting using an opamp). A Sallen-Key can be many shapes.

Comment: @Mattman I'm really glad you added that fact!! The Sallen Key paper, TR-50 from 1954, covers a great many filter types -- not just one or two. And they cover far, far more filter topologies than what is usually associated with them. Popularizers, such as Don Lancaster, limited themselves to just two topologies. But in no way, was that all that Sallen & Key carefully discussed. And for the many topologies, they covered filter shapes, and how to factor arbitrarily complex transfer functions into relatively approximate, and simpler and more implementable design sections.

Comment: @Swedgin the name typed out is the filter characteristic and not the filter type. That name defines that it is low-pass having a cut-off of 500 kHz that is maximally flat in the pass band (aka Butterworth).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> One is Salena Kay, and the other I don’t know what is called.

**Sallen Key with unity low pass gain**: -

[image]

Pictures taken from [this useful web calculator](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPseikiLowkeisan.htm).

---

**Sallen Key with gain setting resistors**: -

[image]

Pictures taken from same calculator page as above - scroll down

---

**MFB or multiple feedback**: -

[image]

Note that the low frequency gain of the above MFB circuit is \$-\frac{R3}{R1}\$

Pictures taken from [this useful web calculator](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuLowkeisan.htm).

> Question: what is the difference and which is better to use?

The MFB uses one more component but can operate at higher gains. I suggest you use this information (and knowledge of your application) to google for further information.

Comment: Just a note. The Sallen Key image you borrowed doesn't match the OP's image, which is a Sallen Key where gain or damping can be chosen, but not both at once, with gain that must be less than three.

Comment: @jonk - thank you and fixed!

Comment: +1. Anyway, I wish the US Air Force would free up TR-50 by Sallen & Key. It is infinitely better than their published paper a year later. Everyone should master that paper. It is really good and I don't know of anything better, since, for self-learning. Lots of very hard to read, highly mathematical books are around now. But nothing I've seen that provides such good insights for so many types of common filter types in so few pages. Stupid US Air Force insists on receiving justification and approved release only on individual basis. It is insane we are still in that situation.

Comment: @jonk I've not come across *TR-50 by Sallen & Key*!!!

Comment: It's a beautiful and much longer and more detailed than the 1955 paper. TR-50 was published within MIT in 1954 under contract with the US Air Force. To get it, you have to contact the right department within MIT and they will then get, and forward, your written justification to the Air Force who may then approve your receipt of a copy. You won't find it on the web. It is so much better and provides examples, lots and lots more tables, etc, offers really good ways to think about the topic, and address worked out examples. It's theory based, but I'm a way that guides and helps, not confuses.

Comment: I made phone calls to get to the right department. Just discovering that it existed is a story of its own. Once I had my copy, I grew quite angry that it hasn't been released to the public. It still makes me mad when I think about it.

Comment: another point to add w.r.t. Sallen-Key vs MFB is: Sallen-Key provide for easier selection of
circuit components, and at unity gain, it has no gain sensitivity to component variations. The
MFB shows less overall sensitivity to component variations and has superior high-frequency
performance

Answer (score 0):

first question is what do you want? if you want to make an active filter you should know where you want to use it! which op-amp do you want to use? they always mention about making filter with them in the datasheet.

Comment: There is no mention of what part is being use. Henceforth, you can assume that the op-amp is an ideal device.

Answer (score 0):

For the sallen-key Filter...

Q = 1/(3 - k)

For butterworth response which is a maximally flat pass band and roll off of -12dB/octave (-40dB/decade)....

Must have Q of 0.707 which means a gain,k of 1.59. So set RA = 5k6 and RB = 10k

Then cut off frequency, fc = 1/(2 * pi * R * C)

Where R=R1=R2 and C=C1=C2

[image: Filters]

[image: Filters2]